# What causes alert checkbox to display additional checkbox?

Tags: javascript, textarea, onkeypress

I have a `textarea`, and my `onkeypress` works just fine with hit.

However, if I keep trying to type the 256th character, my alert box eventually (2nd or 3rd time) also prints a little `checkbox` that I did not write. It says

`[] Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs`

I'm confused as to whether the browser (Firefox) or Javascript is doing that. Here is the code.

```
function warnOverDescLen()
{
var misc_text = document.forms["InvGenPayDonation"]["TransDesc"].value;

  if(255 < misc_text.length)
  {
    alert("You cannot enter more than 255 characters.");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
.
.
.
<textarea rows="4" cols="60" name="TransDesc" id="TransDesc" 
onkeypress="return warnOverDescLen();" ></textarea>
```

Comment: The browser adds that. You have no control over it.

Comment: The answers to the OP were especially helpful, because they got me to experiment with switching status field colors when a problem occurs, and then, as part of verifying the form, disabling the status field, because I don't need it to be part of the POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser adds that functionality to prevent sites from annoying users with a barrage of (thread-locking) popup messages.

To avoid the issue, I would recommend you display the message ("You cannot enter more than 255 characters.") in a small label near the text box instead of using `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the browser, asking you if you want to disable repetitive alert messages. This is helpful in some development if, for example, an infinite loop is displaying alert messages.
This gives a way to ignore that scenario. Otherwise it is a user aesthetic feature.